# Combine two json files into one class instance

Tags: c#, json, .net, merge

I have a question regarding supplying data to class instances. So I have two json files with daily data which I ultimately need to have as one class instance (for ease of later use):

Json 1:

> {id:1,days:[{day:1,data1:blah!, data2:blah2, data3:blah3},{day:2,data1:blah!, data2:blah2, data3:blah3},{day:3,data1:blah!, data2:blah2, data3:blah3]}

Json2:

> {id:1,days:[{day:1,data4:blah!, data5:blah2, data6:blah3},{day:2,data4:blah!, data5:blah2, data6:blah3},{day:3,data4:blah!, data5:blah2, data6:blah3}]}

And I have class

```
public class rootObject
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public Days[] data {get; set;}
}

public class Days
{
    public Datetime day {get; set;}
    public string data1 {get; set;}
    public string data2 {get; set;}
    public string data3 {get; set;}
    public string data4 {get; set;}
    public string data5 {get; set;}
    public string data6 {get; set;}
}
```

I am using

```
rootObject myData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<rootObject>(json1);
```

which nicely provides half the data.

What I need now is to add the data from the second file, while matching the dates, to the same myData so I can have one object from which I can later pull all fields at once.

Currently I'm creating a second myData2 with data from second Json and then I use nested loop with if to combine them:

```
foreach(Day x in myData.data){
    foreach(Day y in myData2.data){
        if(x.day == y.day){
            x.data4 = y.data4
            // (and so on)
        }
    }
}
```

Event though the above works I use this quite a lot and it make the code a mess. There has to be a quicker and more elegant way to do this.

Comment: why both json has the same id?

Comment: I'd make 2 types to deserialize those different jsons. And then another type to transform into data you need. The fransformation is inevitable and it's identical to what you did.

Comment: id is the same as this is the client ID, this part of data is irrelevant. Most importantly I need to merge the 'days' to have as one class instance which can later be used

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your choice of representing two distinct data sets as a single class, but then again I'm not getting the full picture. If what you're trying to achieve is an informed choice, `Newtonsoft.Json` has methods for merging two JSONs (though you have to use the untyped `JObject` approach and convert to typed after merging). You could do something like the following:

```
var first = JObject.Parse(jsonString1);
var second = JObject.Parse(jsonString2);

var merged = new JObject();
merged.Merge(first);
merged.Merge(second);

var result = merged.ToObject<YourAggregatedClass>();
```

Comment: siemanko Polska ;-)
The reason I'm using it this way is that this is data about client's marketing campaing. One set coming from my internal sources (APIs) and the other one coming from the client. The data is 'per day'.Ultimately I am building a webapp in blazo and need to present data from both sets in one DataGrid, hence the need to have all this data merged as an instance of a class.

Comment: @MichałPoterek fair enough - the code above should hopefully work for you then. Did you give it a try?